# How many different ways to split 26 cards into 3 sets

Tags: combinatorics

After shuffling the pack of 26 cards, the dealer asks one of the players to separate the pack into 3 parts, each containing at least one card.  She then asks the other player to reassemble the 3 parts in one of the 6 possible orders of his choosing, before she deals the next ‘hand’.  In how many different ways can the first player separate the pack as described?  (Hint: think about the spaces between the cards.)

The answer to this one is 25!/2!*23!
I think that it is we put 2 spaces between 25 cards since we have have 2 spaces am I correct?
Also did our professor told as that it is 25 and not 26?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: The spaces cannot be together, or at the head or at the tail.

Comment: so this is why its 25 and not 26?

Comment: Parentheses, please, if you are not going to use MathJax.  What you have written, 25!/2!*23! is correctly read as $\frac {25!}{2!}\cdot 23!$, which is not what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed ${25 \choose 2} = {25! \over 2! 23!}$ and the number $25$ comes from a series of thought experiments:

- First, as is obvious, you want to put $2$ "divider" cards into the deck.  This would seemingly give ${28 \choose 2}$ possibilities.  But this isn't the right answer because the two dividers can be adjacent (meaning: middle stack is empty) or one can be at the beginning (first stack empty) or end (last stack empty).

  - We can rule out the three empty stack cases with Inclusion-Exclusion, but that's not the best method here.
- The better method is to glue together a divider and its following real card.  So you have $26$ objects: $24$ remaining real cards, and $2$ divider-glued-to-real-card combos.  This gives ${26 \choose 2}$ possibilities.  Since each divider is followed by at least one real card (the one it's glued to), this means the middle and last stacks are guaranteed to be non-empty.  But if a divider-plus-card combo is the first thing, then the first stack is empty.
- To rule that out, have a real card come first, then you can freely arrange the remaining $23$ real cards and the $2$ divider-glue-to-real-card combos.  This guarantees all three stacks are non-empty.  The number of possibilities is ${23+2 \choose 2} = {25 \choose 2}$

Visualization: $C =$ real card, $D =$ divider, $[DC] =$ divider-glued-to-real-card:

The possibilities are: $C X_1 X_2 ... X_{25}$ where among the $25\ X_i$ we have $23\  C$s and $2 \ [DC]$s.

Comment: Is there anything stopping me generalizing this? Say choosing `k` cards into `m` sets I should get $ k - 1 \choose m - 1$

Comment: @DylanMadisetti - Yeah I think it generalizes like that.